# Number of spanning trees in a graph with a vertex of degree N

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I was given the following question on an assignment and had no idea how to solve it(without laplacian matrices), so naturally, I got it wrong. The answer is supposed to be found using combinatorics. The question is below.

Given a complete graph that is provided below, find the number of spanning trees in the graph if vertex 10 were to have a degree of 1 or if vertex 10 had a degree of 4.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xveL.png

So, is there a formula to deal with a question like this(using combinatorics)? The question also stated that I should know that the number of spanning trees in a complete graph is: $$n^{n-2}$$

I found that the answer for degree 1 is: $$9^{9-2}=9^7=4782969$$
For degree 4 I have no idea.

Comment: There is a formula to compute the number of spanning trees of a graph called the [matrix tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem)  but I doubt you will need it in this case.

Comment: Maybe you can try first to see what happens with a complete graph on 5 vertices and see what is going on when, say vertex 5, has degree 1,2,3. It should give you some clue and it should be a bit more manageable. Or maybe try first with a graph with 4 vertices to make it even easier.

Answer (score 2):

The pictured graph is $K_{10}$  Consider the case where vertex $10$ is of degree $1$.  There is one edge $e$ incident on vertex $10$ and it must be in the spanning tree.  If we delete $e$ from the graph, the graph that remains is a $K_9$ and has $9^7$ spanning trees.  Each of these spanning trees, together with edge $e$, gives a spanning tree of the whole graph.  So the answer is $9^7$.

The question is harder when the degree is $4$ because, while you must have at least one of the edges incident on vertex $10$, you can have $2,3,\text{ or }4$ of them.  Also, when you delete those edges, you don't necessarily have a spanning tree of the remaining graph.

Good luck.

Comment: There are also $9$ possibilities for which edge $e$ can be.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I don't interpret the question that way.  I think it asks what is the number of spanning tree of graph isomorphic to the pictured one, except that vertex $10$ has degree $1$.

Comment: I guess I can see how you could read it like that. In my opinion, that would be a poorly phrased question, but of course people do get asked poorly asked questions sometimes.

Comment: I don't see how one could read it any other way, frankly, but I guess that's what makes horse races.

Comment: For each fixed spanning tree on 9 vertices, you can get 9 distinct spanning trees by adding an edge from vertex 10 to the remaining 9 vertices hence you have $9^8$ spanning trees I would guess

Comment: I'm reading it as "number of spanning trees in which vertex $10$ has degree $1$" or "degree $4$", respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Like many problems about spanning trees of $K_n$, this one is best solved by  [Prüfer codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence).

The $10^8$ spanning trees of $K_{10}$ corresponds to strings of $8$ integers from $1$ to $10$. A key fact about the bijection is that it maps spanning trees in which the $i^{\text{th}}$ vertex has degree $d$ to strings in which $i$ appears $d-1$ times.

So the answer is $9^8$ (not $9^7$) when vertex $10$ has degree $1$, because then you are choosing strings of $8$ integers from $1$ to $9$, and $\binom{8}{3}9^5$ when vertex $10$ has degree $4$.

(By the way, it is very easy to see that the answer for degree $1$ cannot be $9^7$. If so, we would have at most $10 \cdot 9^7$ trees in which any vertex is a leaf, by symmetry - but $10 \cdot 9^7 < 10^8$, and so you would have some trees left over that don't have any leaves at all, which is impossible.)

---

The above assumes you're looking for a spanning tree of $K_n$ in which vertex $10$ has some fixed degree.

If you're instead modifying $K_n$ by deleting some edges incident to vertex $10$ until it has that degree, and then finding all spanning trees, we can still use the above to find the answer, but it takes a bit of work.

Let $\tau_d(G)$ denote the number of spanning trees of a graph $G$ in which vertex $10$ has degree $d$. Let $H$ denote the graph obtained from $K_{10}$ by deleting vertices out of vertex $10$ until it has degree $4$.

Then by symmetry, $\tau_d(H) : \tau_d(K_{10})$ is the same ratio as $\binom{4}{d} : \binom{9}{d}$, since we have $\binom 4d$ ways to pick $10$'s neighbors in $H$ and $\binom 9d$ ways to pick them in $K_{10}$. We can compute $\tau_1(K_{10}) = 9^8$, $\tau_2(K_{10}) = \binom81 9^7$, $\tau_3(K_{10}) = \binom82 9^6$, and $\tau_4(K_{10}) = \binom83 9^5$ by looking at Prüfer codes, and use the ratio to compute $\tau_1(H) + \tau_2(H) + \tau_3(H) + \tau_4(H)$, the number we're interested in.

Comment: Although you say that the answer for degree 1 is 9^8, my answer of 9^7 was somehow marked as correct by my instructor......

Comment: It's possible then that saulspatz's interpretation of the question, rather than mine, is correct. (See the comments to their answer.)

Comment: I have edited my answer to address both versions of the question.